# How to identify associations originating from an array attribute in an UML object diagram?

Tags: uml, object-diagram

Like you can see from the diagram it has three objects. Object_1 has a variable-sized ordered array with references to objects 2 and 3 in that order which is exactly the thing I want to say with the diagram. My problem is that I didn't see anything in the UML standard specifications when I browsed them through for a notation to do something like this.

How do I fix this diagram so that it would be a valid object diagram according to the UML standard? Or is it even possible? Does UML specify a way to say something like this?

[image: uml object diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specification of what an object diagram (what you show) is (see a full explanation [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html#object-diagram)). So whatever you do will be right (or wrong :-))

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing I would probably have to improvise anyway but that confirms it. Seems weird though that they don't have even something this simple properly specified. I guess people are simply not using object diagrams a lot and therefore the committee didn't see any need to do something about it.

Comment: One of the problems with UML is that it is very complicated and also created by multiple companies working together, which makes its specification very complicated. There are many "bugs" in the UML specification, many things that are not specified and also contradicting specifications. But still, it is the standard... until we have something better.